# Unable to run tests on the terminal

Tags: go

I am attempting to add my Go project to CircleCi for CI. However when it gets to the testing stage I get some errors. I've then tried to run 'go test' locally on my terminal in the Go project and I get the following error.

> 

can't load package: package crypto-compare-go: found packages main (main.go) and handler (main_test.go) in /Users/pocockn/go/src/crypto-compare-go

crypto-compare-go is the name of the parent folder that holds the Go program. It is under

> go > src >

On my machine.

Below is how my project is structured.

[image]

I just want to run go test and it run the tests in my project. I've also tried go test ./... but get the same problem

Answer (score 7):

Your error message explains the problem exactly:

> can't load package: package crypto-compare-go: found packages main (main.go) and handler (main_test.go) in /Users/pocockn/go/src/crypto-compare-go

You have two package declarations in the same package. This is invalid.

`main.go` has:

```
package main
```

and `main_test.go` has:

```
package handler
```

Make them match.

As a special case, if you desire your tests to run in a separate pacakge (i.e. so that you can test the public API, without access to internals), you can name your test package `main_test`, but this must match the other package name, suffixed with `_test`.